# Migration Junit4 to Junit 5 updates @RunWith(DataProviderRunner.class)

Tags: junit, junit5

I am not sure how to migrate this since DataProviderRunner.class which is class that relay on to junit4.

(DataProviderRunner.class is from
`import com.tngtech.java.junit.dataprovider.DataProviderRunner;`

I know that @RunWith is replaced with @ExtendWith

Has anyone done a similar thing and how?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider comes with support for Jupiter, which is JUnit 5‘s default engine. Use this.

Here’s the documentation: https://github.com/TNG/junit-dataprovider/wiki/Migration-guides#migration-to-junit5

Comment: I have tried already and have some errors. Will update them tomorrow.